# EOFException while calling Ksoap2 magento api

Tags: magento-1.7, exception, soap-api-v2

I am getting EOFEXCEPTION while calling ksoap2 magento apis. mainly while call productinfo

```
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, name);
request.addProperty("sessionId", "anksf123123123");
  env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://testdomain.com/Mage3.php");
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
         Object object = env.getResponse() ;
        System.out.println(object.toString());
```

I am getting error :

```
07-30 12:48:45.204: W/System.err(21083): java.io.EOFException
07-30 12:48:45.204: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:95)
07-30 12:48:45.204: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:179)
07-30 12:48:45.204: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
07-30 12:48:45.204: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:628)
07-30 12:48:45.209: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
07-30 12:48:45.209: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
07-30 12:48:45.209: W/System.err(21083):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
07-30 12:48:45.209: W/System.err(21083):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openInputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:113)
07-30 12:48:45.209: W/System.err(21083):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:167)
07-30 12:48:45.209: W/System.err(21083):    at com.outthinking.utils.SOAPServiceForCustomAPI.sendRequest(SOAPServiceForCustomAPI.java:74)
```

Comment: what does this line do `androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://testdomain.com/Mage3.php");` ?

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. 
its our domain url to call magento api .